# Run Pythons Tornado serving ssl and unsecure sl at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, ssl, tornado

I have some sites that connect to my Tornado API that need a ssl and some that do not. Is there a way one Tornado Api can server both ssl and non ssl requests?
Any help greatly appreciated.

I have the following code that only works if a site is not a ssl..

```
    app = Application()

    app.listen('8000')

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And I have have this that works only for secure ssl clients ..

```
    app = Application()

    app.listen("8080", ssl_options = {
        "certfile": os.path.join(lib_dir, "mydomain.crt"),
        "keyfile": os.path.join(lib_dir, "mydomain.key"),
        })

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot serve HTTP and HTTPS traffic on the same port. You can call app.listen twice with two different ports to start both SSL and non-SSL servers.

Comment: Hey Ben! Thanks a mill. I didn't think it would be that simple. :) Tornado Rocks!